# Expander control that Slides up

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, animation, controls

I'm trying to build an animation effect where pressing a "button" at the bottom of the screen, causes an animated "slide up" of a StackPanel - a bit like the slide up that's achieved by an Application Bar when the menu is shown.

I've been trying a few effects based on the sample at http://www.cespage.com/silverlight/tutorials/wp7tut24.html which uses animations like:

```
                            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateButtonTransform"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" To="180" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
```

However, using this sample, doesn't give me the desired effect - as the content container height "jumps" even though the content scale itself is animated.

I've also played with animating the container/content height:

```
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Content"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="200" Duration="0"/>
```

... but this doesn't really work as the Height is overwritten by the StackPanel (and I can't use MaxHeight as that's not the right sort of Property for animation).

Any ideas/pointers about what I should be animating?

---

Note - before anyone comments about WP7 design guidelines... this is the customer design/spec and it does seem to fit OK within Metro :)

Comment: Can you post the structure of the template of the Expander, xaml tags and x:Name only? No need for VisualStateManager tags.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are after? Basically my current test wp7 app is a standard wizard app with an expander in which I have 4 buttons in  a stackpanel exactly as in http://www.cespage.com/silverlight/tutorials/wp7tut24.html. (I am now thinking about moving to a fixed size panel instead and trying to move it on/off screen rather than trying to scale it though)

Comment: Sorry, brain-fart at 2AM - I didn't see the link. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion - I tried a few things... and in the end I went with:

- I placed the expander and its Content inside a container (a Border)
- I used a Grid layout to place this expander on the screen
- I animated a TranslateTransform to slide this expander on/off the screen.

Some condensed code:

```
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ViewStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderTranslateTransform"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" To="0" Duration="0"></DoubleAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderTranslateTransform"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" To="154" Duration="0"></DoubleAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Margin="0,0,0,0">
                        <Border.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="BorderTranslateTransform"></TranslateTransform>
                        </Border.RenderTransform>
                        <Grid>
                            // stuff here
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you animate the margin?

This isn't a dependency property and so it takes a bit of effort but can be done. (I have an example somewhere if you need one.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - sadly the solution didn't want to work (kept not drawing the content area)

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the WP7 SDK installed on this machine, so everything is from memory. Take it with a grain of salt. And, I'm assuming that it's ok to use hard-coded sizes (otherwise it's much much trickier).

First, for consistency, make the `IsExpanded` property `false` by defalut:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsExpanded", typeof(bool),
    typeof(Expander), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

On the ContentPresenter named "Content" add `Height="0"`.

In the `Storyboard` of `VisualState` named "Expanded" add this animation:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Content"
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                 To="200"
                 Duration="0:0:1"/>
```

In the `Storyboard` of `VisualState` named "Collapsed" add this animation:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Content"
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                 To="0"
                 Duration="0:0:1"/>
```

Adjust the `To` and `Duration` properties of the animations to your liking.

For a *slide* animation of the content, try removing the animation that is working on "ContentScaleTransform". This animation will cause more of a 'growing' or 'stretching' effect in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... but this is what I've already tried in "I've also played with animating the container/content height:" - and it doesn't work because the contained stackpanel ignores the Height. It might work if I use a ScrollViewer instead... will try... but currently looking at maybe not animating the height - but just moving the panel on/off screen instead. Thanks again (sorry it's not more positive news!)

Comment: In your code the `Duration` was set to zero, this will make the height of the `ContentPresenter` jump to 200 pixels. Adding a non-zero `Duration` will make it animate. Have you tried non-zero `Duration` and it didn't work?

Comment: This did puzzle me too (I used the code from that article) but it seems like zero is the default ("Automatic") value and is interpreted as 1 second - see some explanation in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.duration.aspx